# jQuery function fires one time

Tags: jquery

I have a function that when written in a test app worked fine it fired any number of times when I moved the code to a page that acts as if it is three pages the btnCal function will only fire one time. I have used `location.reload();` to solve the issue but do NOT feel this is a good coding standard and I do not like the screen falsh when I do the reload
any suggestions on what I am doing wrong or thoughts on how to fix this are more than welcome

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DEX.css">


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>-->
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
<!--<script src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>--><!-- this is the path within the folder-->
<!--<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script><!-- this is the path to another folder-->

<script> 
$(document).ready(function () {

$(function() {
$("#dis1").hide();
$("#dis2").show();
$("#dis3").hide();
$("#btn1").hide();
$("#btn2").hide();
$("#newboxes1").show();
$("#newboxes2").hide();
$("#newboxes3").hide();
//$('#age').attr('readonly',false);
$("#age").focus();

});//End Load Page 1


  //Clear Input Box & Reset Drop Down 
    $("#btnClear").click(function (){ 
    $("input[type=text]").val(""); 
    $("textarea").val("");
    $("#DDHt").get(0).selectedIndex = 0; 
    $("#DDWt").get(0).selectedIndex = 0;
    $("#DDSex").get(0).selectedIndex = 0;
    $("#cgLBW").html("");//Clear Output Data Cr Cl
    $("#cgABW").html("");
    $("#cgTBW").html("");
//$("#age").attr("readonly", false);
//location.reload();
    $("#age").focus();

  });//End Clear Input


    $("#btnCal").click(function (){
    var gvAge = $('#age').val();//Gets the Value of input text box
    gvAge = parseInt(gvAge);
    var gvHt = $('#ht').val();

    var gvHtUt = $("#DDHt").prop("selectedIndex");
    gvHtUt = parseInt(gvHtUt);
    if (gvHtUt == 0){
    var htin = gvHt * 0.3937;
    var htcm = gvHt;
    }else{
    var htcm = gvHt * 2.54;
    var htin = gvHt;
    }

    var gvWt  =  $('#wt').val();

    var gvWtUt = $("#DDWt").prop("selectedIndex");
    gvWtUt = parseInt(gvWtUt);
    if (gvWtUt == 0){
    var wtlb = gvWt * 2.2;
    var wtkg = gvWt;
    }else{
    var wtkg = gvWt * 0.4546;
    var wtlb = gvWt;
    }

    var gvSex = $("#DDSex").prop("selectedIndex");
    gvSex = parseInt(gvSex);


    var gvSrCr  =  $('#SrCr').val();
    gvSrCr = parseFloat(gvSrCr);


    <!--  ++++ Ideal Body Weight in Kg ++++ -->

    if (gvSex == 0){
    var LBW = 50 + (2.3 * (htin - 60));
    }else{
    var LBW = 45.5 + (2.3 * (htin - 60));
    }

    var mylbw;
              if (wtkg < LBW){
                  mylbw = wtkg;
              } else {
                  mylbw = LBW;
              }

              //return mylbw;
    //alert("B "+mylbw);

    var CrClLBW;
    CrClLBW = ((140 - gvAge) * LBW) / (gvSrCr * 72);
    CrClLBW = CrClLBW.toFixed(1);
    if (gvSex == 1){
    CrClLBW = CrClLBW * 0.85;
    CrClLBW = CrClLBW.toFixed(1);
    }

    if (wtkg > mylbw){
    var weight = mylbw + (0.4 * (wtkg - mylbw));
    }else{
    var weight = wtkg;
    }

    var CrClABW;
    CrClABW = ((140 - gvAge) * weight) / (gvSrCr * 72);
    CrClABW = CrClABW.toFixed(1);
    if (gvSex == 1){
    CrClABW = CrClABW * 0.85;
    CrClABW = CrClABW.toFixed(1);
    }

    var CrClTBW;
    CrClTBW = ((140 - gvAge) * wtkg) / (gvSrCr * 72);
    CrClTBW = CrClTBW.toFixed(1);
    if (gvSex == 1){
    CrClTBW = CrClTBW * 0.85;
    CrClTBW = CrClTBW.toFixed(1);
    }

    $("#cgLBW span").html(CrClLBW);
    $("#cgABW span").html(CrClABW);
    $("#cgTBW span").html(CrClTBW);

  });//End Calculate Function   




$("#btnSP1").click(function (){
//function showpageone(){
//$("#age").val("");
//$("#ht").val("");
$("input[type=text]").val("");
$("#dis1").hide();
$("#dis2").show();
$("#newboxes3").hide();
$("#newboxes1").show();
    $("#cgLBW").html("");//Clear Output Data Cr Cl
    $("#cgABW").html("");
    $("#cgTBW").html("");
    //location.reload();
$("#age").focus();
});


$("#btnSP2").click(function (){
//function showpagetwo(){ 
$("#dis2").hide();
$("#dis3").show();
$("#btn1").show();
$("#newboxes1").hide();
$("#newboxes2").show();
var P = 45 * 2;
P = parseInt(P);
$("#myO span").html(P);
var T = $("#myO span").html();
T = parseInt(T);
T = T/2;
$("#myC span").html(T);
var gvAge = $('#age').val();//Gets the Value of input text box
gvAge = parseInt(gvAge);
gvAge = gvAge + 100;
$("#myA span").html(gvAge);
var gvHt = $("#ht").val();
gvHt = parseInt(gvHt);
$("#myH span").html(gvHt);
//$('#age').attr('readonly',true);//this makes the Age Input Box Read ONLY
});


$("#btnSP3").click(function (){
//function showpagethree(){
$("#dis3").hide();
$("#dis1").show();
$("#btn2").show();
$("#newboxes2").hide();
$("#newboxes3").show();
//$('#age').attr('readonly',false);
});


$("#btn1").click(function (){
//function returnpageone(){
$("#dis2").show();
$("#dis1").hide();
$("#dis3").hide();
$("#btn1").hide();
$("#newboxes1").show();
$("#newboxes2").hide();
$("#age").focus();
});


$("btn2").click(function (){
//function returnpagetwo(){
$("#dis3").show();
$("#dis2").hide();
$("#btn2").hide();
$("#newboxes2").show();
$("#newboxes3").hide();
});

});
</script>



    <title>DIV Hide & Show |  External JQuery & CSS Folder</title>

    </head>

    <body>

    <H1>E.Dwight Norris R.Ph.</H1>

         <div id="dis1" class="newbtn">
    <input type="button" value="Click for Page 1" id="btnSP1"></input>
    <input id="btn2" type="button" value="Return to Page 2"></input>
         </div>

         <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes1"></div>

    <div id="dis2" class="newbtn">
    <input type="button" value="Click for Page 2" id="btnSP2">

    <fieldset id="FS1"class ="bx2">

       <p>
          <label id="Lage">Age</label>           
          <input type = "text"
                 id = "age"
                 size="8"/>
          <label id="Lyr">years</label>

          <label id="Lht">Height</label>
          <input type = "text"
                 id = "ht"
                 size="8"/>
          <p>
             <select id="DDHt">
               <option value = "0">cm</option>
               <option value = "1">in</option>
             </select>
          </p>

          <label id="Lwt">Weight</label>
          <input type = "text"
                 id = "wt"
                 size="8"/>
          <p>
             <select id="DDWt">
               <option value = "0">Kg</option>
               <option value = "1">lb</option>
             </select>
          </p>

          <label id="Lsex">Gender</label>
          <p>
             <select id="DDSex">
               <option value = "0">Male</option>
               <option value = "1">Female</option>
             </select>
          </p>

          <label id="LSrCr">Sr Cr</label>
          <input type = "text"
                 id = "SrCr"
                 size="8"/>
          <label id="Lmgdl">mg/dl</label>

        </p>       
    </fieldset> 


    <fieldset id="FS2"class ="bx3">
  <label id="LCM">Calculation Method</label>
    <label id="LcgLBW">Cockcroft and Gault Lean BW<sup>Eq 1</sup></label>
    <div id="cgLBW"><span></span></div>
  <label id="LmL1">mL/min</label>
  <label id="LcgABW">Cockcroft and Gault Adjusted BW<sup>Eq 2</sup></label>
  <div id="cgABW"><span></span></div>
  <label id="LmL2">mL/min</label>
  <label id="LcgTBW">Cockcroft and Gault True BW<sup>Eq 3</sup></label>
  <div id="cgTBW"><span></span></div>
  <label id="LmL3">mL/min</label>

  </fieldset> 


  <input type="button" id="btnCal" value="Calculate"></input>
  <input type="button" id="btnClear" value="Clear Form"></input>

    </div>

        <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes2">I am Page 2
    <div id="myO">Value P  <span>remove</span></div>
    <div id="myC">Value T  <span>remove</span></div>
    <div id="myA">Age  <span>remove</span></div>
    <div id="myH">Height  <span>remove</span></div>
        </div>


         <div id="dis3" class="newbtn">
    <input type="button" value="Click for Page 3" id="btnSP3"></input>
    <input id="btn1" type="button" value="Return to Page 1"></input>
        </div>

         <div class="newboxes" id="newboxes3">I am Page 3
    <p>I am set to 900px wide and 780px height for Printing</p>

         </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Suggestion #1: check the console.

Comment: Next time, post only relevant code, not all your site

Comment: `$(document).ready(function () {})` and `$(function () {})` are equivalent. jQuery documentation suggests `$(function () {})` is preferred. I also prefer it because it is shorter. You only need ONE of these wrapping your 'onload' stuff.

Comment: sorry about all the code If I remove the $(function(){ the btnCal function will not fire but I can navigate the page I agree the OnLoad stuff is not good code

Comment: You are probably slowing your page down enough that some of your bindings work. See my answer to re-org your bindings inside your 'onload' area so they bind when the doc is ready.

Answer (score 0):

either use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

or

```
 $(function() {
```

You are initializing the onload function twice.

Answer (score 0):

I started rewriting that for you but basically, you have loose bindings. 
In a nut shell, all your 'click' bindings should be inside your 'onload-doc ready'. Use '$(function() {})' just once. '$(document).ready(function () {})' and '$(function () {})' are equivalent. jQuery documentation suggests $(function () {}) is preferred. I also prefer it because it is shorter. You only need ONE of these wrapping your 'onload' stuff.

In a short form, your code should look more like this:

```
$(function() {
  // Do stuff 'onload' here
  clearMyForm();
  // All your bindings should go here
  $('#btnCal').on('click', function(event) { calculateStuff(); });
  $('#btnSP1').on('click', function(event) { doStuff1(); });    
  $('#btnSP2').on('click', function(event) { doStuff2(); });
});


function clearMyForm() {
  $("#dis1, #dis3, #btn1, #btn2, #newboxes2, #newboxes3").hide();
  $("#newboxes1, #dis2").show();
  //Clear Input Box & Reset Drop Down
  $("#btnClear").click(function (){
  $("input[type=text]").val("");
  $("textarea").val("");
  $("#DDHt, #DDWt, #DDSex").get(0).selectedIndex = 0;
  $("#cgLBW, #cgABW, #cgTBW").html("");
  $("#age").focus();
}

function calculateStuff() {
  if(a > b) { 
    doStuff3();
  } else {
    doStuff4();
  }
 }

 function doStuff1() {
  if(a > c) { 
    doStuff4();
  } else {
    doStuff2();
    clearMyForm();
  }
 }
```

You get the idea. This way your bindings occur when the page is ready. You can also then call and recall your functions more cleanly as well.

Comment: thanks but I still can only fire the btnCal ONCE her is the cade change below<script> 
$(document).ready(function () {
setPage();
//$(function() {


$("#btnClear").on("click",function(event){clearPage();});
$("#btnCal").on("click",function(event){calCrCL();});

$("#btnSP1").on("click",function(event){showpageone();});
$("#btnSP2").on("click",function(event){showpagetwo();});
$("#btnSP3").on("click",function(event){showpagethree();});

$("#btn1").on("click",function(event){returnpageone();});
$("#btn2").on("click",function(event){returnpagetwo();});

});//End Ready

Comment: Does this occur in all browsers? The fact that it works once means the binding is working. So either something is removing the listener (I don't see anything in your calc function from orig question like that). Or something is erring. Do you get an error in the console? 
Also, try adding logging to see if it is really firing nth time:
    `$("#btnCal").on("click",function(event){
      console.log('Firing btnCal event');
      calCrCL();
    }); `

Comment: I found the error with the use of a few Alert functions my defined place to print the CrCl was in a span and I was not clearing the span I was clearing the HTML I can not thank you enough for the valuable lesson on Document ready function and this has made a dramatic improvement in my code design I would like to ask why do I need the .on and (event) syntax as I was able to write the code without these as $("#btnCal").click(function (){showpagetwo();});

Comment: As for bindings, jQuery docs suggests using `on('', ...)` as their latest and greatest way to bind as it allows binding multiple events (ie: `on('click keypress'...)` ). So I personally prefer to use it all the time, even if there is only one bind event I am looking for at the time as it allows me to easily add/change events on which to bind (which is handy when testing with ie/ff/chrome/etc., sometimes). By all means, the shortcut versions (eg: `click`) are not deprecated so are perfectly valid as well.

Comment: As for the `event` being passed along, it does not really matter if you do not need it. And even when you do, most browsers keep track of it for you. The one that does not is Firefox. If you do not pass it along and then try to reference `event` without referencing it by its full scope `window.event`, you will get an error. So as a general rule, I try to remember to pass it along as a matter of form even when I do not need it. Kind of like remembering to end my lines with `;` even though js does not require it to terminate a statement at a line end.